# separate builds in separate directories

Tags: makefile

I'm sure this is a totally normal thing to do, but I can't figure out how to get make to do this.

I have a compiler that generates make dependencies of the usual form:

```
M/A.o : M/A.hs
M/B.o : M/A.o
```

So I write a rule to compile %.hs into %.o, add a rule to link the binary, include the dependencies file, and all is well.  But I want to have several binary targets with different flags.  E.g. I want build/test built with -DTESTING and build/profile built with -prof.  So I need to keep the .o files in a separate tree, where they will be compiled with special flags.

The straightforward way I can think of would be to have dependencies that look something like this:

```
build/test/M/A.o : M/A.hs
build/test/M/B.o : build/test/M/A.o

build/profile/M/A.o : M/A.hs
... etc.
```

And then rules so that %.hs to build/test/%.o compiles with -DTESTING, etc.  I think this would work, but it's clumsy, means preprocessing the deps file to add all that build/whatever/ prefix stuff, and would multiply its size by however many kinds of builds.

VPATH appears to be designed for this sort of thing and my idea was that I could set the VPATH and compiler flags depending on the target, and it almost works, but:

```
%.o: %.hs
    @mkdir -p build/M
    cp $< build/$@

VPATH = build

main: M/A.o M/B.o
    cat $^ >$@

M/A.o : M/A.hs
M/B.o : M/B.hs
```

The first time the main target wants to run 'cat M/A.o M/B.o >main' which seems contrary to the gnu make documentation that says $^ should include the include the VPATH directory in which the dependency was found.  Curiously, if I remove 'main' and make again, this time it uses the correct path.  This is GNU make, 3.81.

What's going on here?  Is there a better way to build with different flags?  VPATH seems like a clumsy tool, surely there is a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Make is working correctly. It tries `cat M/A.o M/B.o >main` the first time because it can't find the prerequisites it needs, but it knows a rule for `M/A.o' and`M/B.o`(<em>not</em>`build/M/A.o' and `build/M/B.o`) and expects that that is what the rule will produce. If you remove `main` and try again, it will find `build/M/A.o' and`build/M/B.o` via VPATH.

Let's modify this makefile in stages. First we change the VPATH so that it can find the `.hs` files (Make is good at using things *there* to build things *here*, not vise-versa, and that's what VPATH is good for), and change the rules slightly:

```
build/%.o: %.hs
    cp $< $@

VPATH = M

main: build/A.o build/B.o
    cat $^ > $@
```

Now for the different object directories.

```
build/test/%.o build/project/%.o: %.hs
    cp $< $@

VPATH = M

test: build/test/A.o build/test/B.o
    cat $^ > $@

project: build/project/A.o build/project/B.o
    cat $^ > $@
```

Then we simplify those last two rules, so that it's easy to add more object files and binary targets:

```
OBJECTS = A.o B.o

test: $(addprefix build/test/,$(OBJECTS))
project: $(addprefix build/project/,$(OBJECTS))

test project:
    cat $^ > $@
```

Now for the different compiler flags:

```
build/test/%.o: FLAGS += test_flags
build/project/%.o: FLAGS += proj_flags

build/test/%.o build/project/%.o: %.hs
    @echo building $@ from $^ using flags $(FLAGS)
    cp $< $@
```

Finally the dependencies. This is a little tricky. Suppose you want the dependency `B.o : A.hs` to apply to however many object  you have. This is one approach:

```
OBJECT_PATHS = build/test/ build/project/

# The following is from the included file generated by the compiler
$(addsuffix B.o,$(OBJECT_PATHS)) : A.hs
```

To generate lines like that, I'd pipe the raw lines (e.g. `B.o: A.hs`) through `sed 's/\(.*\):\(.*\)/\1:\2/'`, and note that if you want to put this in a makefile command, don't forget to double the `$` signs to preserve them for the shell.

I know that's a lot to absorb. Take it one step at a time and let us know how it works out.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, but I think I omitted some important details in the interest of brevity.  Namely that I have a whole bunch of src dirs, e.g. M/ N/ N/O/P/ etc.  To avoid collisions the .o's need to go in a parallel hierarchy in build/.  Since VPATH wants to flatten the src dir maybe it can't help me.  However, experimenting with removing VPATH and using 'build/A.o : M/A.hs' yields 'Nothing to be done for build/A.o' unless the implicit rule is 'build/%.o: M/%.hs', I guess % doesn't match /s.

Comment: The other thing is that your addsuffix trick seems equivalent to preprocessing the deps to multiply each rule by the number of OBJECT_PATHS... less source, but presumably expands into the same thing so I might as well generate it all explicitly.  It's also a little more complicated because a dep B->A must be written $OBJECT_PATH/M/N/B.hs : $OBJECT_PATH/M/Q/A.o, i.e. .o's must be prefixed on both sides of the colon.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't solved your problem by now or are experiencing further problems, best give the autotools (automake and autoconf) a chance. They'll quickly build you a Makefile that supports more configurable and flexible out-of-tree builds.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  I eventually gave up on make entirely.  I don't doubt it's eventually possible to do what I want with enough black macro magic, but meanwhile there are build systems, like waf, that specifically support this kind of thing.